# Only allowing form to be submitted if from a certain URL? (iframe, Laravel)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I'm currently building a service in which I need people to be able to submit a form, through an iframe which they'd have on their own site, however I need it to only be from the domain listed in their User model.

I know this is possible, however I need a solution whereby users cannot edit any JS to allow it to work on a domain that it shouldn't (through inspect element etc.).

Anyone got any solutions? Any help at all greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the parent page from an iframe unless both the iframe and the parent are on the same domain.